# I am trying to fetch data between date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data between two date .I am fetching data from my database.Problem is that submit_date1 column is not in my database so I am storing submit_date and submit_date1 data in same variable. And then try to fetch data.

```
 $submit_date = isset($_REQUEST['submit_date']) ? $_REQUEST['submit_date'] : '';
    $submit_date1 = isset($_REQUEST['submit_date1']) ? $_REQUEST['submit_date1'] : '';
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($submit_date));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($submit_date1));
    $user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select * from diary_user_form_storage where category_name='delivery_form' AND DATE(submit_date) <='".$date2."' AND DATE(submit_date) >= '".$date2."'");

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFQcu.png

Comment: you're using the same variables here, look at your own code again

Comment: use BETWEEN https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: Fred@yes problem is that I have only current date in my table .click on link please .In image you can see example  .  I need data between date   from one table .

Comment: Gyandeep Sharma @I will see

Comment: @sanjaykumar which one is bigger $submit_date or $submit_date1

Comment: Tarun@submit_date

Comment: @sanjaykumar you may try the following: DATE(submit_date) >= $submit_date1 AND DATE(submit_date)  <= $submit_date

Comment: Tarun@thanks man i was wrong becouse I was not selected date minimum to max, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be helpful for you.
get the result from MYSQL table between two dates in php. try this code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name");
$first_date=$_POST["first_date"];
$second_date=$_POST["second_date"];
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '".$first_date."' AND '".$second_date."' ");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is answer of this question.Thanks everyone.

```
$submit_date = isset($_REQUEST['submit_date']) ? $_REQUEST['submit_date'] : '';
$submit_date1 = isset($_REQUEST['submit_date1']) ? $_REQUEST['submit_date1'] : '';
$date3 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($submit_date1));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($submit_date));
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select * from diary_user_form_storage where category_name='delivery_form' AND DATE(submit_date) >='$date3' AND DATE(submit_date)<= '$date2'");
```